# Twilio Logs on Console for Error 21614

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php, error-log

I have successfully attempted sending SMS to a phone number using Twilio REST API in PHP. Currently I am using a trial account. I can see logs on Twilio console too. When I attempt to send SMS to an invalid number, Twilio REST API gives me error:
    Error 21614 - 'To' number is not a valid mobile number.
I can't view this error in Twilio Programmable SMS logs or Debugger Logs. So when I submit a bulk of numbers to Twilio, how can I find at the end, that which numbers failed to receive the SMSs because of error 21614, on **Twilio Console**? Currenty, I do not want to log it through my PHP code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

If you want to go through the console you can see this [link](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181868-Troubleshooting-undelivered-Twilio-SMS-messages) as you do not want to manage it via `php`

---

**For managing at your end with `StatusCallback`**

You need to use optional parameter `StatusCallback` and specify a callback URL where Twilio will `POST` each time your message `status` changes to one of the following:

- queued,
- failed,
- sent,
- delivered,
- or undelivered.

Twilio will `POST` the `MessageSid` along with the other [standard request parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request#request-parameters) as well as `MessageStatus` and ErrorCode. If this parameter passed in addition to a MessagingServiceSid, Twilio will override the Status Callback URL of the [Messaging Service](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/messaging/send-messages#messaging-services). URLs must contain a valid hostname (underscores are not allowed). You can learn more about it [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/messaging/send-messages)

you can add your php code there to keep track of every new message and keep updating the logs for that message.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually I am trying to look out for the numbers which were not event attempted to send message to by Twilio. These numbers not at all shown on Twilio and are to managed purposefully from the project itself.

Comment: in that case you are left with the option of using php i think and managing them at your own server